# Why is the wired or signal type (wor) disallowed for typedefs in SystemVerilog

Tags: system-verilog, synplify

In SystemVerilog I CAN do

```
typedef logic [15:0] bus16;
typedef reg [15:0] reg16;

interface myif;
   bus16 mybus;
   wor [15:0] myotherbus;
endinterface
```

But I CAN'T do

```
typedef wor [15:0] wor16;

interface myif;
   wor16 myotherbus;
endinterface
```

I get "unknown variable declaration type"

It seems, at least in my Synplicity version, typedefs of 'wor' is not permitted.

Is this a limitation defined in the IEEE1800 spec or is it perhaps a bug?

Answer (score 1):

SystemVerilog separates the concepts of ***network/net*** types (which are like resolved signals in VHDL) and ***variables*** (unresolved) from ***data*** types. The net types `wire`, `wand`, `wor`, etc. have built-in resolution functions with a default data type of `logic`. The following net declarations are equivalent:

```
wor [15:0] w;
wor logic [15:0] w;
typedef logic [15:0] bus16;
wor bus16 w;
```

Similarly the following variable declarations are equivalent:

```
logic [15:0] v;
var logic [15:0] v;
typedef logic [15:0] bus16;
var bus16 v;
bus16 v;
```

In most places, the `var` keyword is implicit when declaring variables.

There is a `nettype` declaration that binds a data type with a user-defined resolution function. Unfortunately there no way to define a `nettype` with one of the built-in resolution functions, so you would have to write your own *or* function.

Comment: So you are saying (in your first example) that logic has an implied wor like function?

Comment: @JasonM , yes wired-or and wired-and are the two built-in Boolean resolution functions. A basic `wire` is just highest strength wins.

Answer (score 0):

It is disallowed because System Verilog Standard does not allow using `nets` in `typedef`s. Sorry, no other explanation.

You can look at the syntax in paragraph 6.18. Follow `data_type` definition. It is based on system verilog `var`s but does not include `net`s (6.8).

You can define a new net type using the `nettype` construct, but it still does no allow you to use other net types. However, you can create them with a custom resolution behavior (check 6.6.7). It is a special syntax and does not fit for simple renaming. BTW, neither `wor` nor this are synthesizable.

So, your best bet is to use macros:  `` `define wor16 wor[15:0] ``

Comment: In my world 'wor' is synthesisable.  It results in an OR gate of each of the bus signals from each source.  Thanks for the tip and the explanation.  I am new to SystemVerilog (I really know VHDL)